# Migration from SQL Server and issues in applications and database connection string of application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, database-migration, sql-server-2014

I am working on the project where we are migrating from SQL Server 2000 to 2005 and also migrating from 2005 to 2012 or 2014. There are 30 databases that supports more than 45 applications. Some of the applications are Windows desktop and some are web based application.

My question is if I change the server than there will be problem in connection string and I have to change the connection string of all the applications in the code, right?

Is there any way that I do not have to change the connection string in the code of all the application?

What do you prefer?

PS: Most of the application are in C#, ASP.net

Comment: What do you mean by *connection Url* ? Do you mean the **connection string** that establishes the connection to the database?? This has nothing to do with an URL however....

Comment: Yes I mean connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if done correctly, the connection properties should be exposed via a file or application setting.  Updating the file/setting to point to the new SQL Server should be quite trivial, although it will require quite a bit of coordination, especially for the client apps.  Web apps should be simple, IMO.  I am willing to bet you will hit more issues related to permissions and such, because in my experience, it's the logins/pwds/roles that aren't migrated properly.

Comment: What type of precautions I should take to migrate logins/pwds/roles correctly. and move databases correctly ?